# Outlets to UILabel Not Found in XIB even after declaring Outlets in header file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I am developing an iPhone app, and I am the following problem.

I have declared the outlets and properties for UILabel in my header file, but in XIB I am not able to find the outlets for UILabel.

Here is a snippet which shows my header file declaration of IBOutlets for UILabels:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your NIB's class is set to FirstViewController by opening it on Interface Builder and pressing CMD+4 then checking that the CLASS field is set appropriately.

Comment: Class property shows UIView. FirstViewController option is not there.

Comment: On Interface Builder, in your document window, make sure you have File's Owner selected instead of your view, then press CMD+4.

Comment: Thanks you for patiently answering my silly questions. :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Put an `IBOutlet` directive on your property.

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UILabel * test;
```

Comment: even this doesnot work. I tried putting IBOutlet in property as you said. But no differnce.

Answer (score 0):

Lately, I have been having this problem when I open projects in the "Recent Projects" list when first launching xcode. Opening .xcodeproj file itself restores the links for me.

Comment: Thanks anyways but my problem has been solved by Rog. Anyways it is nice that you gave your input. May be this would help me sometime in future :)